# PS3 Left Joystick & FPS problem: moves both character & camera

Tags: games

So, this has been a weird issue for me...let me preface this by saying that I've installed xboxdrv & jstest, and that my PS3 controller has worked in the past on games with a top-down perspective. However, when trying games with a 1st person perspective, things got strange.

You know how in most console games the left stick moves the player, and the right stick moves the camera? Well, the left stick for me is moving both. For example: if I move forward in a game, I will move forward, but the camera will pan upwards until I'm looking at the sky and moving forward when only touching the left stick. The same thing happens backwards, only I move backwards and wind up looking straight down.

I can find a balance by moving the right stick in the opposite direction, but this doesn't create an equilibrium: instead, the camera constantly bobs up and down as the joysticks fight for dominance.

I've tried every available pre-made controller setups and even trying to make my own key bindings in-game in multiple FPS games, but to no avail. I've tried using jstest, but I'm unsure if my problem can be solved in it. I apologize if this is a common problem with a simple solution, but I can't find anything about this online.